# On high load server is blocked by "connection pool has been exhausted, either raise MaxPoolSize or timeout"

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, connection-pooling, npgsql

I use NHibernate with Npgsql 3.1.5.0 and when testing with high load sometimes server is completely blocked by this exception.
[image: Threads]

After downgrading to postgresql 9.4.4 it happens on higher load but is still reproducable.

I also re-checked that all NHibernate sessions and transactions are correctly disposed so no connections are opened on my side.

After some time I have 0 sessions opened and still getting "Connection pool has been exhausted". It's weird that I can't reproduce it on my dev machine (only on production - Windows Server 2008 R2).

pgAdmin - Server Status actually shows those 140 connections (and 20 extra) there doing nothing (query = commit or empty, state = idle).

What can cause it?

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1232